# Sveltejs render html attribute conditionally

Tags: svelte

How can one render an attribute on a html element conditionally with svelte? To be clear, I am not talking about a conditional value, but the attribute presence itself.

For instance, I want to autofocus only the first item in this list of inputs:

```
{{#each codeInputs as codeInput, index}}
  <input bind:value="inputCodes[index]" type="text" autofocus> 
{{/each}}
```

The attribute `autofocus` should be there only for the first item. I could use index to detect the first item, but `autofocus="{{index===0}}"` renders `autofocus="true"` or `"false"`, so that is not what I need.

Also see https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/259

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it — [it does work](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.30.0&gist=1d1ed6ecccb21a49a058c0343b186a39). Svelte doesn't set the *attribute* when it sees something like `autofocus='{{xyz}}`, it sets the *property* — the attribute must be a string (which is unhelpful) whereas the property can be a boolean.

Comment: Excellent, that covers [Boolean html5 attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes) defined in html, as you explain in https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/301. My use case is solved by that.

Comment: But there is a related question: how about [String attributes](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.30.0&gist=d3c9e949965b10d276f429cfa8aea82b)

Comment: Currently, that's not possible. We haven't yet encountered a situation where it's a problem (as opposed to a theoretical concern), but if it's causing a bug in your app, please raise an issue!