# How to have conditional autofocus in Svelte 3

Tags: svelte-3, svelte-component

I would like to shift focus on my page in response to keyboard input. With Svelte it seems that the simplest way is to use the autofocus attribute. However I cannot get conditional autofocus attributes to work.

Here's a simple repro of my problem: https://svelte.dev/repl/0861d097921d4a35957f016a8c35cfe6?version=3.44.3

Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible in Svelte 3?

Conditional autofocus was possible in a previous version of Svelte according to this question: [Sveltejs render html attribute conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714809/sveltejs-render-html-attribute-conditionally)

And conditionality is possible for other attributes in Svelte 3 according to this question: [How to have a conditional attribute in Svelte 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59027947/how-to-have-a-conditional-attribute-in-svelte-3)

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to add a key block around the thing to make it re-run on every update of the `focusIndex`.

Example

```html
{#key focusIndex}
    {#each items as item, index}
        <input autofocus="{index === focusIndex}" value={item} on:keydown={(ev) => test(ev)} />
    {/each}
{/key}
```

Not the prettiest solution, but might unblock you.

Comment: Thanks, this does work, but seems inefficient. I'll wait a little longer to see if there's a better way before accepting this answer.

Comment: Hmm, my real code is more complicated than the example, and this approach also messes up my blur/focus handling (I think because the element gaining focus gets destroyed by the refresh)

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly an answer to the exact question I asked, but the alternative that I've gone with is to use `bind:this` on the elements to create an array of the DOM elements and then in the `keydown` handler explicitly call `.focus()` on the DOM elements.

Example: https://svelte.dev/repl/83934cd7924741a8a4c5a620f79d5bb5?version=3.44.3